# PHP regex to get contents of a specific span element

Tags: php, regex

I need some help ... I'm a bit (read total) n00b when it comes to regular expressions, and need some help writing one to find a specific piece of text contained within a specific HTML tag from PHP.

The source string looks like this:

```
<span lang="en">English Content</span><span lang="fr">French content</span> ... etc ...
```

I'd like to extract just the text of the element for a specific language.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are plenty of HTML parsers available for PHP. I suggest you check out one of those, (for example: [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/)).

Shooting yourself in the foot with trying to read HTML with regex is a lot easier than you think, and a lot harder to avoid than you wish (especially when you don't know regex thoroughly, and your input is not guaranteed to be 100% clean HTML).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, and you're probably right. I thought that a simple regex would be the quickest and easiest way of achieving this, as I'm not parsing a whole HTML document, just a little string that will always look like the example.

Comment: Then you are probably still better off with two calls to strpos() to get the indexes for the substring you need.

Comment: Just to note; PHP 5.x includes the SimpleXML DOM parser, which makes doing this sort of thing nice and straightforward. You can easily use an XPath query to traverse the DOM and pick out the parts you need.

Comment: Does it handle (possibly ill-formed) HTML as well?

Answer (score 0):

(Bad, not working) example which shows why you should not use regex for parsing html.

```
/<span lang="en">(.*)<\/span>/
```

Will output:

```
English Content</span><span lang="fr">French content
```

More stuff to read:

[Parsing: Beyond Regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000253.html)

[For-the-2,295,485th-time-DO-NOT-PARSE-HTML-WITH-REGULAR-EXPRESSIONS](http://blog.mikeseth.com/index.php?/archives/1-For-the-2,295,485th-time-DO-NOT-PARSE-HTML-WITH-REGULAR-EXPRESSIONS.html)

Comment: No. That is what I mean by "shooting yourself in the foot".

Comment: I agree using regex for parsing html is not the thing you want to do, but I tried to answer the question.

Comment: Sorry but that's wrong on at least two fronts (and if you can't figure out which two, that's a good reason why you should be using a parser).

Comment: @cletus: *lol* :-) @Karsten: If you want to find out the error no. 1, simply run your regex against the given example.

Comment: Thanks for idea, Karsten. I modified it slightly, and it works for me:

<span lang="gd">(.*?)</span>

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm suitably castigated. :)

Comment: @David Heggie: Yours is better, but it will fail at: "<span lang="gd">foo <span>bar</span> foo</span>"

Answer (score 0):

There's this most awesome class that lets you do SQL-like queries on HTML pages. It might be worth a look:

[HTML SQL](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3086.html)

I've used it a bunch and I love it.

Hope that helps...